# AWS DynamoDB with ASP .Net Core 3.1.0 Identity 2.2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I have to integrate Asp .net core identity 2.2.0 with AWS DynamoDB.I am using the .net core version 3.1.I searched for the reference but I didn't get any good one. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have got one reference from 
https://github.com/miltador/AspNetCore.Identity.DynamoDB.

It sounds like someone wrote this and didn't maintain it. I have downloaded the Source code from this repo and updated the same to .net core 3.1.0 and identity 2.2.0[and also updated the startup file]. Now it's working fine for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are trying to use DynamoDB instead of our provider to integrate AWS Cognito service as the ASP.NET Core identity provider? You can find out about the Cognito provider here: https://github.com/aws/aws-aspnet-cognito-identity-provider

Comment: Yes Norm.I have a requirement that create identity related tables in to the dynamoDb instead of Sql Server.I found one sample project from this link https://github.com/miltador/AspNetCore.Identity.DynamoDB

But when I updating the same into the Asp .net core 3.1 and identiti 2.2.0 showing errors in the startup file

Thanks for your replay.