# Identity Server 4 | MVC | Set User in Context by RequestPasswordTokenAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

First of the all - I check in google and stack-overflow 2 days....
I found thousands examples and tutorials by still have missing point and don`t have full picture in the head.

So:

My architecture:

1) Identity server
2) 5 +/- MVC websites (Like Production website, Global admin, Help desk, etc...)(which have be protected by identity server )
3) Dozens micro services (which have be protected by identity server )

Now - What I not completely understand:

1) Login:
For now I setup the redirect flow. I Mean.... in website I setup Identity server like:

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44396";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

                options.ClientId = "<<Here is client ID>>";
                options.ClientSecret = "<<HERE IS PASSWORD>>";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("api1.read");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
```

And

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now, if user try to open page with `Autorize` attribute - user redirect to identity server login there and back to protected page. Everything working well.

But....

1) I want login on the MVC page. Without redirect to Identity Server.
I checked internet and found that I need use `identityserver resource owner password flow`

Then I setup IdentityServer as:

```
 new Client {
                    ClientId = "myclient",
                    ClientName = "My first client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,// GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("superSecretPassword".Sha256())},
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "api1.read", IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email},
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc" },
                    RequireConsent = false
                 },
```

And in My MVC I can get token :

```
public static async Task HandleToken(this HttpClient client, string authority, string clientId, string secret, string apiName)
        {

            var accessToken = await client.GetRefreshTokenAsync(authority, clientId, secret, apiName);
            client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetRefreshTokenAsync(this HttpClient client, string authority, string clientId, string secret, string apiName)
        {
            var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(authority);
            if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

            var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
            {
                UserName = "<<HERE IS USERNAME>>",
                Password = "<<HERE IS PASSWORD>>",
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = secret,
                Scope = apiName
            });




 var user_info = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest() { Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint, Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken });

Here I have all user claims and Now I want set them in Controller => User




                if (!tokenResponse.IsError) return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
                return null;
            }
```

Now I get token.....Good.........but

2 Questions:

1) How I can set the User Identity inside Controller.User (ClaimsPrincipal)?

**** UPDATE
I found the one solution

I can use  `HttpContext.SignInAsync` and after I got token and user info from code above - I can do sign in for my Web MVC project and set manually user claims. If this is good approach?

2) All manipulation with User profile data, like ChangePassword, Update FirstName, LastName, etc...
How I need to do this??
Build Microservice for Identity Membership?

P.S - In IdentityServer I use Asp Identity :

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

And last question is:

If I want to use `DynamoDB` as user store - then I need to build by custom `Identity Provider`?
(Correct??)

I found this solution in `github`, and I just need to update to `Asp Core 3.1`

```
https://github.com/c0achmcguirk/AspNetIdentity_DynamoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you just need the configure your API for Identity Server then it will be populated automatically when the client made a proper request. (which includes its access token)

> Sample API Configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddCors(r => r.AddDefaultPolicy(o =>
                                           o.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                                           .AllowAnyHeader()));
  services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                        {
                          options.Audience = "apix"; // this apis scope
                          options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; // Identity server url                                                
                         });

  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
     options.DefaultPolicy =
                     new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

          // ...
            app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

          // ...
        }
```

And you also need to decorate your API method with `[Authorize]` attribute.

For the second question, it is a matter of preference. There is a template named QuickStart that includes user operations with IdentityServer4 which handles that in an MVC way. You can also create WEB APIs and expose them. And you may not need to create a separate microservice for that since IdentityServer is a WEB application itself.

For the last question, people usually modify old repos to make it work with DynamoDb. Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578191/aws-dynamodb-with-asp-net-core-3-1-0-identity-2-2-0)

> Edit:
>   For the question `How to set up the MVC to set User Claims after ResourceOwner flow login`

You need to implement a `IProfileService` service and register it in the startup. (IdentityServer)

```
public async  Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
  var subject = context.Subject;
  var subjectId = subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault().Value;
  var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId); 
  var claims = GetClaimsFromUser(user,context.Caller); // here is the magic method arranges claims according to user and caller
  context.IssuedClaims = claims.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes, Identity Server is MVC - but I dont want get to User access to Identity server.
I have 3 websites, for 3 different type of user and I would like to get to user chnage his data inside this websites.

And - Yes - The API automaticly fetch the user data - my question how setup the MVC to set User Claims after ResourceOwner flow login

Comment: But _userManager means that my MVC website need to get access to database. Its not good. If I do redirect flow - I get the User data in claims Automatically.

Comment: @DavidAbaev it is not the client app. It should reside on the IdentityServer side. And `IProfileService` belongs to IdentityServer not to AspNetIdentity.

Comment: Now I add in my client app:

    Scope = apiName + " openid profile"

And After I get the token I call UserInfo endpoint:

 var user_info = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest() { Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint, Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken });


And I have All my claims....
Now I want to add this claims to Controller => User

Comment: @DavidAbaev you should be doing that over configuration not manually.

Comment: Ok....but again....In mu client app (MVC website) _ I call RequestPasswordTokenAsync for get token. 

After I got token - How I put the CLAIMS inside MVC controller - in User property?

Comment: Please see my Update question. If use  HttpContext.SignInAsync and set manually user claims in MVC Website is OK?

Comment: @DavidAbaev you also need to call `httpContext.AuthenticateAsync` method in order to `Controller.User` gets populated. So both methods should be called there.

Comment: So this approach is ok?

1) Get token
2) Then with token - Call UserInfo endpoint for get all claims
3) Then mannualy call SignInAsync  and AuthenticateAsync  for populate User claims in MVC website project?

Comment: @DavidAbaev it seems, for your requirements, it's the only viable option.

Comment: YEah - after 2 days googling - this is what i found...

If you see here any security problem ?

Comment: And for Edit User details - the best way to build dedicated microservice for CRUD operation and send to there http requests?

Comment: @DavidAbaev well making it over http would be overkill. And the identity server doesn't provide such endpoints. Your microservice will be handling it using AspnetIdentity

Comment: So you mean -work with dedicated service over gRPC/webSocket etc.??
For me right now its doesn`t matter. 
I want implement:

user Login to web site (Solution we fount with you ))
Open account - change his first name and phone number - clicks save.

I want to change this data and show result to user.

Comment: So I can send HTTP request to Account microservice (API) - which protect by Identity server 4 and the API do his job. (Its can be done by manually work with database or use AspNetIdentity) and return in response result. If use websocket or another event bus - its asynchrony way and I need to make or poling or websocket with you to show the result to user. Correct?

Comment: @DavidAbaev I misunderstood the HTTP part, and for the last part, it sounds fair.

Comment: YEah)
Thank you for all your help.